# Error in boxplot, argument "x" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, r-markdown, boxplot

I'm trying to make a boxplot in R markdown with two variables (named "suicides/100k pop" and "sex" in the .xlsx file, with "sex" being nominal with options male/female) but it's not producing the plot.

> 

```
suicidedata = as.data.frame(readxl::read_xlsx(
  path = "(...)\suicidedata.xlsx",
))
```

```
boxplot(
  formula = "suicides/100k pop" ~ "sex",
)
```

The error:

> Error in boxplot.default(formula ="suicides/100k pop" ~ "sex", : argument "x" is missing, with no default calls:  ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> boxplot -> boxplot.default Execution

What do I do to make it print the boxplot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can change the double quotes to `backquote` and specify the `data`

```
boxplot(
    formula = `suicides/100k pop` ~ sex, data = suicidedata)
```

---

A reproducible example with

```
data(iris)   
names(iris)[1] <- 'Sepal.Length/100k pop'
```

The double quotes  wouldn't work  here

```
boxplot("Sepal.Length/100k pop" ~ Species, data = iris)
```

> Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) :    invalid term in
>   model formula

while the backquotes work

```
boxplot(`Sepal.Length/100k pop` ~ Species, data = iris)
```

[image]